# regex: change html before saving in database

Tags: php, regex

Before saving into database i need to

---

1. delete all tags
2. delete all more then one white space characters
3. delete all more then one newlines

for it i do the following

1. `$content = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', "", $content);`
2. `$content = preg_replace('/\n/', "NewLine", $content);it's for not to lose them  when deleting more then one white space character`

   `$content = preg_replace('/(\&nbsp\;){1,}/', " ", $content);`

   `$content = preg_replace('/[\s]{2,}/', " ", $content);`
3. and finnaly i must delete more then one "NewLine" words.

after first two points i get text in such format-

```
NewLineWordOfText
NewLine
NewLine
NewLine NewLine WordOfText &quot;WordOfText WordOfText&quot; WordOfText NewLine&quot;WordOfText
...
```

how telede more then one newline from such content?

Thanks

Comment: You delete more than one whitespace, except newlines, and you delete more than one newlines. Why not delete more than one whitespace, including newlines?

Comment: i need to save newlines!!! let's assume i have `\n\s`. in this case i will get only one `\s`, but i need to save `\n` too.

Comment: `strip_tags()` is a much faster and more effective method of removing HTML

Answer (score 3):

First of all, while [HTML is not regular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and thus it is a bad idea to use regular expressions to parse it, PHP has a function that will remove tags for you: [`strip_tags`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

To squeeze spaces while preserving newlines:

```
$content = preg_replace('/[^\n\S]{2,}/', " ", $content);
$content = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "\n", $content);
```

The first line will squeeze all whitespace other than `\n` (`[^\n\S]` means all characters that aren't `\n` and not a non-whitespace character) into one space. The second will squeeze multiple newlines into a single newline.

Comment: +1. That question should be required reading for users writing their first question tagged "html."

Comment: +1 for strip_tags. HTML isn't regular and is a pain to try to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use nl2br() and then preg_replace all `<br /><br />`s with just `<br />` then all `<br />`s back to \n?